# what is the meaning of "to be" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> John considers this conflict of interest **to be** the main hindrance towards establishing good governance.

I want to know why to be has been used here.

Comment: It doesn't 'have' to be used. You can omit it.

Comment: It has the same meaning as the finite "... that this conflict of interest is the main hindrance ...". Just two different ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

"to be" is a [verb in this case](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/to_be.htm).

The sentence simply means "John considers *that* this conflict of interest ***is*** the main hindrance towards establishing good governance."